# IllegalArgumentExcpetion: argument folder does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, build, testng

I am trying to run a testng test using eclipse TestNG run configuraitons.

I provided some arguments and one the argument is a folder "build/private/root/config"

When I run it I am getting

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: build/private/root/config does not exist.
```

In eclipse PackageExplorer I can see the folder "build/private/root/config" but when I actually try to navigate to that directory I only see the folder build/private and folder root is not present.

It is able to process other arguments I provided except for this one

Comment: Can you please add some screenshot of the eclipse TestNG run configuration ? Also please help share the full stacktrace of the error. 
That would add a bit more clarity to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I later found out the eclipse was keeping the root/config folder and files under it in its eclipse-bin folder instead of the build folder.

I changed the path from build/private to eclipse-bin/private which resolved the issue